# Does google search allow querying via API similar to yahoo boss?

Tags: api, yahoo-pipes

Yahoo's BOSS API allows one to query the Yahoo search database and return values back to the calling program for extraction and usage. Does Google offer a similar tool or API for developers?

I understand that Yahoo BOSS is set to begin charging for queries in excess of 10k per day and I have a shipping plugin which pulls data on demand from this engine, so I'm looking to allow the end user to choose their search provider in order that I can spread the risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - the [google custom search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/). There was once a [SOAP API](https://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/), but it is deprecated now.

See [this announcement](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/introducing-google-apis-console-and-our.html)

Comment: thanks! Do you know if the "100 queries/day" limit is per account or per IP address? Yahoo's limit is 10k per day :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. [JSON/Atom Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)