# Google equivalent to Yahoo! Boss

Tags: google-api, yahoo-boss-api, search-engine-api

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485242/does-google-search-allow-querying-via-api-similar-to-yahoo-boss), but I think the answer is not correct.

Yahoo! Boss gives me the access to its entire search index, whereas [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/) allows you to search sites which you yourself provide.

So, I want to know if there is a Google Search API, which allows me to search its entire index like Yahoo! Boss.

Comment: Thanks for that question! I didn't notice that the WebSearch API (http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html) has been deprecated. My product manager won't be happy :-/

Answer (score 2):

> Google Custom Search API allows you to search sites which you yourself provide.

I suspect you are mistaken, with [this pdf searchengine](http://www.pdfsearchengine.org/index.html)

> You can search the entire web

and they're using Google Custom Search.

I'd say that YBOSS is much more straightforward, but since v2 you have to [pay for it](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/coming-soon-%E2%80%93-yahoo-search-boss-v2-a-paid-service-with-web-images-and-news/), and there might be legal issues as to whether with Google you can re-order the results. I suspect you cannot.